# Are the Russian "фрязин" and Thai "ฝรั่ง" (farang) related?

Tags: etymology, russian, thai

In old Russian the word *фрязин* ([fr'az'in], apostrophe means a soft consonant) was used to denote a westerner. Although the word is not used any more, it is kept as part of some place names, such as a town Фрязино.

I wonder if it is connected to the Thai *farang* which is also used to denote a westerner.

Comment: Shouldn't the transcription be fr'jaz'?

Comment: @Alenanno there is no j-sound in this word, you are free to use any transcription you prefer. Russian usually doen not neet transcription, because pronunciation is determined by the spelling.

Comment: There is no `j` sound by itself, of course, but я is not `a` rather it's `ja`, isn't it? I've always seen it transcribed like that.

Comment: @Alenanno no, it's "ja" (iotified) only word-initially, after vowels and after soft and hard signs, otherwise it's "a", similar to the letters e, ё and ю

Comment: @Alenanno I find that this is a helpful guide: http://www.omniglot.com/writing/russian.htm

Comment: @DangerFourpence Thanks, I actually did Russian Phonetics but wasn't aware of that rule...

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: @Alenanno quite a strange table, actually. It creates an impression that after Ч and Щ the "е" and "ё" pronounced differently than after other consonants. This is not true, they are pronounced the same way. The Ч and Щ are always soft, so replacing "е" with "э" and "ё" with "о" does not change anything: the consonants remain soft.

Comment: @Anixx What table? I didn't link any table. :P

Comment: @Alenanno the table linked by Danger Fourpence

Comment: Well pronunciation is determined by spelling as long as the speller never writes "e" for "ё" and you don't consider it important when the speaker mixes up a few "а" and "о" sounds or doesn't know which syllable to put the stress on. Well-known shibboleths for native Russian speakers to spot foreigners speaking Russian.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surprisingly, it appears they *are* related, cognate to *Frank*.

[The Wikipedia article that Alex B. linked](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD) gives an etymology for the Russian *фря́зин* /ˈfrʲa.zʲin/. It derives from the older form *фрѧ́зин* /ˈfrɛ̃.zʲin/ (following loss of nasality of [*ѧ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yus) and a spelling reform). This is a sound-changed version of /ˈfrɛ̃ɡʲin/ by progressive palatalization; this derives from *Frank* + /ʲin/, a suffix for ethnonyms.

[The Thai ฝรั่ง [faràŋ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farang) is reportedly also derived from *Frank*, via Arabic, Persian, or Sanskrit (various forms like *Farangi*, *Faranj*). Cognate terms were used by Middle Eastern traders to refer to the Catholic Western Europeans. Southeast Asian languages have numerous borrowings along that route, so this etymology is plausible. See also [Wikipedia's list of cognate terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Franks&oldid=532555249#Legacy), which includes similar terms in many nearby languages (Indic languages, Malay, Cambodian). [It also appears in *Star Trek*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferengi)

(Not related to English [*foreign*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=foreign&allowed_in_frame=0), which is coincidentally similar.)

Comment: Interesting! A similar thing occurred in the Tupi language, where the word *peró* was coined to designate the Portuguese. The word comes from the archaic form of "Pedro" (cognate of "Peter").

Comment: And _gringo_ is believed to come from _griego_, "Greek".

Answer (score 1):

I think that it must be noted that words *фрязь* means different thing that word *фрязин* does. According to [wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C), *фрязь* means deviation from traditional iconographical painting while *фрязин* is derived from *франкин* as it was noticed in the answer of user "Mechanical snail". Also in wikipedia's article linked there is not word *фрязь* but *фряг*.

A derivation of *фрязь* from *фрязин* can be assumed from [this article](http://iconography.academic.ru/397/%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C) where 
it is noticed that *фрязь* appeared under the influence of artists from Europe. Those artists might be called *фряги* so icons made in their style might be called *фрязь*.